# Can you set up redirects from old Typepad blog entry URLs to new ones after renaming the blog?

Tags: url, typepad

An old client of mine has a Typepad blog that they’re looking to rename. This blog has a custom domain name, owned by the client, so they can change that just fine.

However, individual Typepad blog entries live in a root folder on the domain, like this:

```
blogname.example.com/blogname/2011/10/blog_entry_title
```

If they rename their blog, then this root folder’s name will change, presumably breaking all external links to entries on their blog (of which there are quite a few).

Because they own the domain, they could set up their own server on that domain to redirect to the renamed blog. But is there any way *within Typepad* to set up redirects from the old blog name to the new one?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from the following Typepad KnowledgeBase page, you can’t:

- http://help.typepad.com/add_blog.html

As stated under “Blog Folder”, if you change the name of the blog folder (that’s the root folder on the domain that the blog lives in), links to the old name will break.

Answer (score 0):

You can by adding a  tag in the HTML for the post. On the "Edit Post" page, click the HTML tab in the upper-right corner of the Body. Then paste this at the very top:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='NEW_URL'" />
```

Add your new URL and you’re done. I’m moving all of my Typepad posts over to Medium.